# How to correctly access ArrayList from threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am using `ThreadPool` on my c# application and I need to add and remove items from an "global" `ArrayList`. The threads will be accessing the same `ArrayList` at any time. How should I do this in a safe way? So no threads will try to access the ArrayList at the same time.

I am starting the threads with this:

```
my_args args = new my_args(input, id, this);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(generateKeywords), args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a thread safe wrapper around the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList threadSafeList = ArrayList.Synchronized(list);
```

Note however that even with a synchronized `ArrayList` it is still not safe to enumerate through the list. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3azh197k.aspx) for more information.

Can I ask why you use an `ArrayList` instead of a generic collection? If you use the list as a queue to feed a couple of worker processes, and you are using .net 4.0, then you can use a `BlockingCollection<T>` object. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SyncRoot to lock the array.

```
lock(((ICollection)myArray).SyncRoot)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use lock statement with your array as argument:

```
lock(myArray){
//do what you want, your array will be protected in this block of code
}
```

Comment: its bad practice to lock collection. Better to have seperate object for synchronization purposes

Comment: I aggree using sync objects is a good approach and maybe the best, but why not locking the array? After all it's an object, too. Anyway, using sync objects is at least a more elegant way to solve this, so, yes!, use sync object. Beware to sync the SAME object. For this, you may use static objects.

Comment: Using a separate object also prevents the misconception that the array is actually locked. This code only works if all threads ask for a lock first.

Answer (score 0):

A better option, if you have .NET 4 available, would be to use one of the collections in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).  These all provide thread safe reading and writing without explicitly locking.

(Some of these collections are lock free, some use fine grained locking, but they are all thread safe, without you having to worry about it.)